# Stochastic integral of $\mathrm{sin}(X_t+Y_t)\mathrm{cos}(X_t+Y_t)$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

As part of an exercise I am doing from stochastic analysis I need to compute the following integral:
$$E(\int_0^x \mathrm{sin}(X_t+Y_t) \mathrm{cos}(X_t+Y_t)dt)$$
where $X_0=0$ and $Y_0=0$. Presumably it is equal to $0$ but I don't know how to show it.

Edit: added the expected value

Comment: First, note that $\cos(x+y)\sin(x+y)=\frac12\sin(2x+2y)$. Do you have an explicit definition of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ ?

Comment: yes i tried that, but that I still  don't know what to do next. The only information I have is that $\begin{cases} dX_t = sin(X_t+Y_t) dW_t \\  dY_t = cos(X_t+Y_t) dV_t \end{cases}$. Where both $W_t$ and $V_t$ are Wiener processess.Please note that I forgot to include the Expected Value

Comment: Hmmm, don't you think these elements should be written in the question?

Comment: To solve this, show that $Z_t=X_t+Y_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and deduce that $E(\sin(2Z_t))=0$ for every $t$.

Comment: Yes, they should. When I look at the question right now I don't really understand why I assumed those information are not vital.

Comment: @Did Actually the whole task is to find for which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ $aX_t+bY_t$ is a Brownian motion. In order to do so I calculated $E(aX_t+bY_t)(aX_s+bY_s)$ and in order for it to be equal to $\mathrm{min} \{s,t \}$ I need to show that the integral from the question is equal to 0.

Comment: This integral is useful to find for which $(a,b)$, $aX+bY$ is a BM, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent BM? Sorry but how?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independant BM, but the process $X+Y$ should be BM

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$d(X_tY_t)=X_tdY_t + Y_tdX_t+d\langle X,Y\rangle_t={X_t\cos(X_t+Y_t)dW_t}+{Y_t\sin(X_t+Y_t)dW_t}+{\sin(X_t+Y_t)\cos(X_t+Y_t)dt}$$

Can you take it from here or do you need me to continue?

EDIT: the two Brownian motions are in fact independent so the last term is 0. As said in a comment, you have to proceed differently.

Comment: Are the two Wiener processes in the definition of $dX_t$ and $dY_t$ independent? If so, the development of $d\langle X,Y\rangle_t$ is false

Comment: $(W,V)$ is a two-dimensional Wiener Process, so i presume they are independent