# Find (a,b) such that aX+bY is a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let
$$\begin{cases}
dX_t = \mathrm{sin}(X_t+Y_t) dW_t \\
dY_t = \mathrm{cos}(X_t+Y_t) dV_t \\
X_0=Y_0=0
\end{cases}$$

Where $(W,V)$ is a two-dimensional Brownian motion and $(X,Y)$ be a strong solution to the set of equations above. Find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $aX_t+bY_t$ is a Brownian motion as well.

I tried to prove it as shown in this question: [Stochastic integral of $\mathrm{sin}(X_t+Y_t)\mathrm{cos}(X_t+Y_t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804896/stochastic-integral-of-mathrmsinx-ty-t-mathrmcosx-ty-t) which required to compute the stochastic integral of cosine and sine but from the comments it follows that there is another way of proving it, which I would be grateful for showing.

Comment: As already explained on the other page, $d\langle aX+bY\rangle_t=a^2d\langle X\rangle_t+2abd\langle X,Y\rangle_t+b^2d\langle Y\rangle_t$ with $d\langle X\rangle_t=\sin^2(X_t+Y_t)dt$, $d\langle X,Y\rangle_t=\sin(X_t+Y_t)\cos(X_t+Y_t)d\langle W,V\rangle_t=0$ and $d\langle Y\rangle_t=\cos^2(X_t+Y_t)dt$, so what is your question really?

Comment: @Did I just don't see how did you calculate $d\langle X,Y\rangle_t$ and I can't really find any explanation on how to calculate it. The closest I got was is that $dX_tdY_t=d\langle X,Y\rangle_t$

Comment: We seem to be seriously lacking of some basic definitions here... How is the covariation process $\langle X,Y\rangle$ defined, already?